# Starting apache server before integration testing not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, testng

I have a web application named as GroupWebApplication. Using pom.xml file I'm just creating the war of my application and deploying to tomcat server. This is basically a maven project. I have added plugins for tomcat7 apache server.

Now what I want that I want to start the tomcat server then run the integration tests and after the completion of the integration tests I want to stop the server. Basically I'm using the testng.xml file of TestNg framework.testng.xml files contains all the classes for integration tests. Manually it's working fine, i.e. starting the server manually and running the test.

Here is the pom file:

```
 <dependencies>

         <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>sGroupWebApplication Integration Test</finalName>
     <resources>
            <resource>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
  <pluginManagement> 
    <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
                        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>resource-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>com.company.integration.test</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>engine</includeArtifactIds>
                            <includes>**\/*.xpi,**\/*.exe,**\/*.so, **\/*.ftl,**\/*.css,**\/*.woff, **\/*.properties,**\/*.png,**\/chromedriver,**\/*.MF</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <server>localhost</server>
      <path>/GroupWebApplication</path>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>s3cret</password>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat7-run</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>

                    <fork>true</fork> 
                </configuration>

           </execution>
           <execution>
            <id>tomcat7-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin> 
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
              </plugin>
            <!-- Java compiler version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                    <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                          <Project-Name>Integration App</Project-Name>
                          <Build-Version>${project.version}</Build-Version>
                          <Build-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Date>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <destDir>javadoc</destDir>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</pluginManagement> 
  </build>
```

testng.xml:

```
  <suite name="INTEGRATION TEST Suite">
    <parameter name="logging"  value="SEVERE"/>
    <test name="GrpApiTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.company.integration.test.DummyIT"></class> 
    </classes>
    </test>
  </suite>
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @
 GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\t_ddbc\Documents\clone_4_ju
ne\demo\GroupWebApplication\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
GroupWebApplication
 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\t_ddbc\Documents\clone_4_june\demo\
GroupWebApplication\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GroupWebApplication
 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory:
 C:\Users\t_ddbc\Documents\clone_4_june\demo\GroupWebApplication\target\surefire-
 reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigur
ator@203e25d3
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.In
vocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetE
xception: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(
ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke
(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(Provi
derFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(Fork
edBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:
75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

On the terminal command I'm using at the root of my project `mvn verify`

Basically this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886816/automatically-starting-stopping-web-server-for-frontend-tests) but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Adding Tomcat 7 and Failsafe to plugins

I took your POM and modified it to make it work (on my machine, I hope it works on yours too). Here is what I changed:

- Added **maven-failsafe-plugin** in the `build/pluginManagement/plugins` element. You have to include the executions otherwise it does not run, as specified on the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html).

  ```
  <pluginManagement>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </pluginManagement>
  ```
- Added **tomcat7-maven-plugin** and **maven-failsafe-plugin** in the `build/plugins` element, otherwise they won't run either. In general, you should mention all plugins you want to use for the build in the `build/plugins` element, plugins inherited from the `pluginManagement` element might not run.

  ```
  <build>
  ....
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ```
- Upgraded version of **tomcat7-maven-plugin** to 2.2 but it also works with 2.0.

### Complete POM

Here is the complete POM I used, for your copy-paste pleasure. ;)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>GroupWebApplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>2.2.1</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>sGroupWebApplication Integration Test</finalName>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement> 
      <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>resource-dependencies</id>
              <phase>initialize</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.company.integration.test</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>engine</includeArtifactIds>
                <includes>**\/*.xpi,**\/*.exe,**\/*.so, **\/*.ftl,**\/*.css,**\/*.woff, **\/*.properties,**\/*.png,**\/chromedriver,**\/*.MF</includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
            <path>/GroupWebApplication</path>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>s3cret</password>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>tomcat7-run</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>run-war-only</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
              <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork> 
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>tomcat7-shutdown</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Java compiler version -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${target.jdk}</source>
            <target>${target.jdk}</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>           
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Project-Name>Integration App</Project-Name>
                <Build-Version>${project.version}</Build-Version>
                <Build-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Date>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <reportOutputDirectory>javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
            <destDir>javadoc</destDir>
          </configuration>                
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement> 
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### mvn verify output

This is how running `mvn verify` on my machine looks like (some lines omitted for brevity). I created two test classes so we can see Surefire and Failsafe run tests: `DummyTest` for unit tests and `DummyIT` for integration tests.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GroupWebApplication 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/sotest/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running DummyTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.185 sec

Results:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [GroupWebApplication] in [/home/sotest/target/sGroupWebApplication Integration Test]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/sotest/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [14 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/sotest/target/sGroupWebApplication Integration Test.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war-only (tomcat7-run) @ GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/GroupWebApplication
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /home/sotest/target/tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /GroupWebApplication
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17:integration-test (default) @ GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /home/sotest/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running DummyIT
Configuring TestNG with: TestNGMapConfigurator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.162 sec - in DummyIT

Results:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:shutdown (tomcat7-shutdown) @ GroupWebApplication ---
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
Aug 20, 2014 9:40:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17:verify (default) @ GroupWebApplication ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /home/sotest/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.015s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 20 21:40:20 SGT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/291M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see:

1. Surefire running unit test `DummyTest`
2. Tomcat starting
3. Failsafe running integration test `DummyIT`
4. Tomcat stopping

I hope that helps! :)

Comment: I got all of this working in a example project here:  https://github.com/djangofan/spring-mvc-testing-example/

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here. The first and lesser problem is that you're using "mvn integration-test" when you should be using "mvn verify".

If you look at the [Maven lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), you will see that the lifecycle phases are ordered "pre-integration-test", "integration-test", "post-integration-test", then "verify".  By running just "integration-test", the "post-integration-test" hook will not run, and the post-integration-test step to stop the server will not execute.

You should also be using the [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) plugin, not the Surefire plugin.  The Surefire plugin is designed for unit tests, and executes during the "test" lifecycle phase, which occurs prior to the pre-integration-test phase.  In other words, your tests are running prior to the Tomcat server starting.  Failsafe, which is basically Surefire but for integration tests, runs during the "integration-test" phase, so they will run after you've started the Tomcat server in the "pre-integration-test" phase.  It is also worth noting that Failsafe won't fail the build until the "verify" step so that your "post-integration-test" work can occur. So it's extra important to use "verify" instead of "integration-test" as your maven command when using the Failsafe plugin.

Comment: @Justin : Thanks for replying. Even i have tried with mvn verify also. But still its not working :(

Comment: @Littlebird Did you also change the plugin from Surefire to Failsafe? Since "verify" alone wouldn't be enough to make this work; you also need to switch from the Surefire plugin to the Failsafe plugin.  Given that the latest version of both is 2.17, and that all the options you're using are also available in Failsafe, the only change you should need to make is to change "maven-surefire-plugin" to "maven-failsafe-plugin" in your XML.

Comment: @Justin: yes i've changed it. <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.17</version>. I'm getting the exception :-   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.surefirereflectionexception java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Comment: @Justin:According to my requirements ,tomcat should start then integration tests should run . But if i check the log then its pointing to Tests 1st.Updated the error logs above.

Answer (score 1):

I also had an issue that resulted in this error, but for me it turned out to be missing file access rights for the account running the tests to the test folder.

Might be something to check out

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted you have defined all plugins in the `pluginManagement` which is on the first glance correct to define versions and configuration. But to get tomcat plugin executed you should mentioned that at least once in your build area as well.

```xml
<project..>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    ...
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Apart from other suggestions like using maven-failsafe-plugin instead of maven-surefire-plugin for integration tests and calling `mvn verify` etc. Furthermore using more up-to-date plugin versions would also be wise.

Comment: It slightly helped me. I have changed the maven-failsafe-plugin version to 2.15 and testng version to 5.13.1. Added plugin tomcat7-maven-plugin outside the <pluginManagement>. Now getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\t_ddbc\Documents\clone_4_june\demo\GroupWebApplication\targe
t\GroupWebApplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specifi
ed).

Comment: Good things is that building of war ,deploying of war , starting and stopping of server is happening.But No integration test happing and getting the filenotfound exception as mentioned in above comment

Comment: In target\GroupWebApplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT\META-INF\, I can see the META-INF folder but not the context.xml file

Comment: You know what the consequences of `<finalName>...</finalName>` is? It is the name of your war file in the target folder. If you have changed it as in your examples you also need to tell that the tomcat7-maven-plugin via `<path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>`.