# Starting of the Apache tomcat server before integration test

Tags: maven, maven-2, testng, pom.xml

I've been looking for an solution for the last 4 days and raised this question as a bounty but still not getting my answer.

Where i've succeeded with the help pf pom.xml file:-
  a) Starting the tomcat server manually using command i.e mvn tomcat7:run. This command also
     help me deploying of my war file to tomcat server and starting the server.
  b) Running my integration tests using testng.xml file configuration on eclipse.

Where i'm failed with the help pf pom.xml file:-

a) Automatically starting of tomcat server.
   b) Running all the integration tests.
   c) Stopping of tomcat server.

This question is posted by me but couldn't find the answer
    [Starting apache server before integration testing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308245/starting-apache-server-before-integration-testing-not-working)

Please help where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## Minimal POM

Here is a minimal POM file that I used to achieve what you want. If it doesn't work for you, please post the output of `mvn -X clean verify` like @BrennaFlood said. Configurations for tomcat7-maven-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin taken from http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html#Use_it_with_selenium_mojo and http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html, respectively.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-with-failsafe</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>2.2.1</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat7-run</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork> 
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat7-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have tomcat start and stop bound to pre-integration-test and post-integration-test phases, but the TestNG stuff is being run during the test phase, which comes before the integration-test phases.  Like the other responder said - you should be running:

mvn clean verify -X

... so that you're catching all the phases up through post-integration-test (and catching all the debug information for troubleshooting), but you should also bind your TestNG components to the integration-test phase.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add this for anyone that is looking to use maven + tomcat7 + testng. Basically my scenario is that some of our IT test needs the running application so they can send some REST call, but some of the IT does not require the server, I split the test cases in two different suites one for the IT that requires the server in the `ServerRequiredIT.xml` and others in `NonServerRequiredIT.xml`, based on that I create two profiles as it follows.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>run-its</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shutdown</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                            <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                                    <value>file:${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/resources/log4j-surefire.properties</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/scripts/ServerRequiredIT.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>testNG-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                            <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                                    <value>file:${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/resources/log4j-surefire.properties</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/scripts/NonServerRequiredIT.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

To run the profiles I use `mvn test -P 'nameOfProfile'`. Important thing here is what the documentation said

> The Failsafe Plugin is designed to run integration tests while the
>   Surefire Plugin is designed to run unit tests

Hope that helps.