# using tomcat9 as deployement server in eclipse as a plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat

I would like to know if there is any way to use the tomcat v9 server as a maven plugin. I'm for nom using this maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

but this one is a bit to old and I've got some problems using it so I would like to know if it's possible and how to use the tomcat V9 server as a plugin instead of using the tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Comment: There is no **tomcat9-maven-plugin** available but you should be able to continue using **tomcat7-maven-plugin** with Tomcat 9. See [Maven plugin for Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41326911/2985643). Can you update your post with details of the problems you are getting due to using tomcat7-maven-plugin with Tomcat 9?

Comment: I’ve got problem with the  dependencies because I use tomcat 9 dependencies an it sometimes doesn’t recognize the dependencies. I also have problem while launching the server because it sometimes doesn’t recognize the tomcat 9 server and fails to start the server