# How to stop Maven Execution

Tags: maven, maven-exec-plugin

I have a mock server which I need to start in Jenkins before  running my Automation tests and then stop the mock server after my tests have run.

This mock server is a maven project and is using `exec-maven-plugin`. I am able to start this server by running the command `mvn exec:java`. However I am unable to stop this maven project through Jenkins. I have read about it and most answers tell to find the Process ID of this Maven project and then kill it. Is there a cleaner and easier way to stop this project ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to start and stop your sever using [goals](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which are part of the maven life cycle.

An example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886816/automatically-starting-stopping-web-server-for-frontend-tests)

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
       <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>

                    <fork>true</fork> 
                </configuration>

           </execution>
           <execution>
            <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to this issue is indeed that you don't know the processId. Consider using `exec:exec` instead with [async](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#async). You'll see that [asyncDestroyOnShutdown](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#asyncDestroyOnShutdown) is set to true by default, meaning it'll shut down once Maven is shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running linux:

`ps aux |grep <project-name>` and then `kill -9 <process id>`